# How to read and validate csv input and the rows

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport, customer-csv

```
public function execute()
{   
    $data = [];
    $file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('refundcsv');
    print_r($file);//display the input file name 
    if (!isset($file)) 
    {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));
    }
    $data = $this->csv->getData($file); //throws error
    print_r($data);
    foreach ($csvData as $row => $data)
    {
      if ($row > 0)
      {
         print_r($row);
      }
    }
    die();
}
```

I want to read the csv input file and validate the rows.  While executing the above code shows an error.

Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in vendor/magento/framework/File/Csv.php

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code,

```
            $csvs  = $this->request->getFiles('importdata');
            if ((isset($csvs['name'])) && ($csvs['name'] != '')) {
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'importdata']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['csv', 'xls']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);

                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('FOLDER_PATH');
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                if (!$result) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath));
                    $this->_redirect('..path..');
                } else {
                    $imagePath = 'FOLDER_PATH' . $result['file'];
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                    $destinationfilePath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath);
                    $csv_data = $this->csvProcessor->getData($destinationfilePath);
                    $headerArray = ["name", "sku", "desc"];
                    $headers = $csv_data[0];
                    $csvHeaders = false;

                    if (count(array_intersect($headerArray, $headers)) != count($headerArray)) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(__("Invalid Formated File"));
                        $this->_redirect('...path...');
                    } else {
                        $count = 0;
                        foreach ($csv_data as $importItem) {
                            if (!$csvHeaders) {
                                $csvHeaders = $importItem;
                                continue;
                            }
                            $mapArr['name'] = $importItem[array_search('name', $headers)];
                            $mapArr['sku'] = $importItem[array_search('sku', $headers)];
                            $mapArr['desc'] = $importItem[array_search('desc', $headers)];
                             ....

                             ....
                            $count++;

                        }
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been Added.', $count));
                    }
                    $this->_redirect('..path...');
                }
              }
```

my csv file saved in meida/FOLDER_PATH

Comment: In my case, I am getting csv input from html form.  How to read that.  I am facing this error while reading  (Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in vendor/magento/framework/File/Csv.php)

Comment: @Mythili Try to save the csv file to a folder. Then, get the file from there and read it.

Comment: How to validate row? If the user fills one column value in CSV and another one is empty.  How to do that?

Comment: In the above code "$mapArr['name'] = $importItem[array_search('name', $headers)];" get the value of column name row values. You can validate this by isset or empty with $mapArr['name']  values in the for loop for each row. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you...It helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

To read csv file try this:

```
protected $csv;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv
)
{
     $this->csv = $csv;
}

//The function name should match your controller path
public function import($file)
{
     if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) 
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));
     
     $csvData = $this->csv->getData($file['tmp_name']);

     foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
         if ($row > 0){
             //Start your work
         }
     }
     die();
}
```